# Merge two similar tables using JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

We have two similar tables with a lot of common columns

Table AA

Id, Name, Active ...

1,A,1

2,null,1

Table BB

Id, Name, Active ...

2,from_B,0

I need to get the AA table, but whenever there is a field in the AA table that is null, but meanwhile with the same id that field in the BB table is not null, I want to rewrite that field from the second table. For above example I want to get this result

1,A,1

2,from_B,1

I tried something like this

select *
from AA left join BB on AA.id=BB.id

And in this query instead of * choose all the fields that appear in table AA, and replace them with corresponding field in BB in case of null, but seems like it is not a good solution when number of common fields are big enough. So is there any nice way to solve this problem by using spring boot and JPA?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **case** in a query that is similar to the if condition.
In your case, the query should be like this

```
select a.id, (case when(a.name is null and b.name is not null) then 
b.name else a.name end) as name, a.active from "tableA" as a
left join "tableB" b on a.id=b.id;
```

also, you can use **if-condition** which is similar to the **case** and it should be like this.

```
SELECT col1, col2, IF( action = 2 AND state = 0, 1, 0 ) AS state from tbl1;
```

OR

```
SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action = 2 and state = 0) then 1 else 0 end) as state from tbl1;
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I mean when number of columns is big enough, is there any way not to write a lot of such lines
      (a.name is null and b.name is not null) then 
b.name else a.name end)

Comment: you should apply conditions if you are comparing table data.